# Quick Test javascript snippet for browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, google-chrome-devtools

Just as we have `http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/` (link inactive on 2021-04-24) to test a C# code quickly, I can also do the same for javascript in chrome debugger tools and Firebug (firefox).

I would be more interested in a tool or some online tool which can run a small piece of javascript and tell if it properly runs in prominent browsers and the result.

**UPDATE:**
I'm a developer and not tester. I don't want to install all browsers on my PC. I like chrome and I can debug/test (for syntax/result) almost every javascript quickly in chrome by just clicking `Ctrl+Shift+J` and pasting my javascript in its console. But that will just test if it works in chrome. I'm not interested in creating a library right now. Google and Stackoverflow helps me get the greatest and latest javascript for a specific task very quickly.

Comment: I know this is a pretty old thread, but checking in to see if anybody found any such tool. It would be invaluable combined with a Unit Testing framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found one way. But it is not that quick and still would like to know better answer. May be some kind of tool which can do this.

**One Way:-**
Write your javascript enclosed in `try-catch` block on [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/) and create its public link. Now check your link with [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/).

Write considerable amount of html (conditionally) using javascript to be able to see the difference on Images given by BrowserShots.

Answer (score 4):

To propose another option 10 years down the line: I would suggest using [JSHint](https://jshint.com/) for this.

The first page as you navigate to their site allows you to simply paste a JS snippet and get information regarding everything from potentially confusing syntax to "minimum ES version" warnings.

Furthermore, you can also install JSHint to your project and have a command to either run manually or slot into your existing build chain to do the same thing locally with custom rules.

Answer (score 2):

I've also found this tool: [JS Compatibility Checker](https://seedmanc.github.io/jscc/), which is based on [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/ciu/index).
Could be helpful, but won't outline every issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a test page to house your snippets, then try them in your target browsers. That has the added advantage of providing a central library for the snippets you do create, so you don't have to go hunting through entire directories looking for that cool little widget you created back in 2010.

Comment: Good Idea. But I don't want to install firefox/opera/safari etc just for this.

Comment: @Ismail: Nota Bene: If you're doing web development you should have them all installed anyway. Sad, but true.

Comment: Testing is done by testers. We have separate CSS  designers. I just work on logic part. Do you still think I should have them all?

Comment: @Ismail: If it's ever your responsibility to fix bugs cross-browser, it seems like a no-brainer to have the browsers in your arsenal. It's not like it costs you anything.

Comment: Agreed! I will install it. I know that's only one of the solution for now. But will you agree that a small portable tool to test crossbrowser ability of a small snippet of javascript or a javascript function will help a lot (in terms of saving time and ease of verifying workability of their code) to not just me but all the web developers?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can check the MDN Web Docs Browser Compatibility section if that interface is available (Eg. window.location - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#browser_compatibility)